# Django save method

Tags: python, html, django, excel, django-admin

So I have a model with a FileField for excel spreadsheet. What I need to do this add another column in this spreadsheet, in each row let user pick from a drop-down list then save it and display it in html. All the picking and uploading will happen through the admin interface. So I have figured out way how to display a spreadsheet in html, however I have no idea how to write this save method. I could really use some hints and tips..

Answer (score 0):

I've found the xlwt package useful when I needed to produce excel files in python. It looks like there are some advances to python excel manipulation technology since I used it though.  http://www.python-excel.org/ has lots of alternatives, plus a detailed tutorial.

As for the Django save method, I came up with a way to update a FileField without creating a temp file, but I'm not sure if it is a good approach.  It took a lot of messing around:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

class Entity(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d',blank=True)
    ...
    def store_file(self, name, data):
        """ This leaves the Entity model unsaved.
        The code that calls this function should
        also call Entity.save() eventually."""

        self.file = ContentFile(data)
        self.file.name = name
```

Comment: This is not what I want. What I want is for save method to add another column into the spreadsheet's html, and for every cell in that column give a dropdown list to choose from and then actually save the html..